# The image not retrieving and show error the input not a valid Base 64 string

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying for at least two hours to solve this but all in vein . 
I am retrieving the image which is stored in database .

```
public Image Base64ToImage(string base64String) {
    // Convert Base64 String to byte[]
    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
    // Convert byte[] to Image
    ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
    Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
    return image;
}
```

And the code using database as :

```
con.Open();
cmd = new SqlCommand("select [s_image] from [2017] where serialno="+serianotext.Text ,con);
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read()) {

    imagepicturebox.Image = Base64ToImage(dr[0].ToString());
}
con.Close();
```

The error show in image
[image]

Comment: Can you post an example string that is stored in the database?

Comment: Store result of `dr[0].ToString()` into local variable and show us what is it in there when you get an exception.

Comment: I assume you are expecting a single row. I would use `ExecuteScalar`, but at minimum you don't need a `while` loop to read one row.

Comment: your code is at risk of SQL injection attacks. Find a tutorial showing you how to use parameterized queries to remove this risk.

Comment: Anyway, the obvious cause of the problem is that `dr[0].ToString() ` doesn't contain a base64 string. Check it's returning what you expected. We can't see what's in it, so you'll have to check it with your debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the value of your base64 string, so I wrote this example. You can use it to make your own code.

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        private static string connectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=my_test_db;Integrated Security=True;";

        public static string ImageToBase64(Image image, ImageFormat imageFormat)
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                image.Save(ms, imageFormat);
                byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
                string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
                return base64String;
            }
        }
        public static Image Base64ToImage(string base64String)
        {
            byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length))
            {
                ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
                Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
                return image;
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string image1base64;

            using(Bitmap image1 = (Bitmap) Image.FromFile("C:\\test1.png"))
                image1base64 = ImageToBase64((Image)image1, ImageFormat.Png);

            using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();

                using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("create table #base64test(id int not null, base64image varchar(max));", sqlConnection))
                    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("insert #base64test(id, base64image) values(@id, @base64image)", sqlConnection))
                {
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int);
                    sqlCommand.Parameters["@id"].Value = 1;

                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@base64image", SqlDbType.VarChar, -1);
                    sqlCommand.Parameters["@base64image"].Value = image1base64;

                    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("select base64image from #base64test where id = @id", sqlConnection))
                {
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int);
                    sqlCommand.Parameters["@id"].Value = 1;

                    using (SqlDataReader rd = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))
                    {
                        if (rd.Read() == false)
                            throw new ApplicationException("An error occurred ...");

                        object[] temp = new object[rd.FieldCount];//[1]

                        // read BLOB trick
                        if (rd.GetSqlValues(temp) != rd.FieldCount)
                            throw new ApplicationException("An error occurred ...");

                        Image image2 = Base64ToImage(((SqlString)temp[0]).ToString());
                        image2.Save("C:\\test2.png", ImageFormat.Png);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```